# WPF Binding Warnings

Tags: c#, wpf

All,
I see below Binding warnings in my Output window. Can some one please explain what is the issue with Binding here. I set several values to ProgressValue' in my ViewModel. But only final value of 100 is set for 'ProgressValue' as shown below.

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): Got PropertyChanged event from ExportControls (hash=6385044)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): GetValue at level 0 from ExportControls (hash=6385044) using RuntimePropertyInfo(ProgressValue): '100'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): TransferValue - got raw value '100'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=58496944): TransferValue - using final value '100'
```

My code is shown below. It's defined in Styles.xaml.

```
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="False" 
             Value="{Binding ProgressValue, 
                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                     Mode=TwoWay, 
                     diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
             x:Name="ExportProgressBar"
             Visibility="Collapsed"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             Background="Transparent"
             BorderThickness="0"
             Foreground="{StaticResource HighlightBlueBrush}"
             />
```

In my View Model, I update the value as shown below.

```
                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    export.ProgressValue = pMeter;
                }));
```

Comment: You should show some code.

Comment: Where is the code? You just copy the Output window.

Comment: None of those are errors. I'm not even sure they are warnings, looks more like a log.

Comment: Your question is not very clear but from what you are describing, is the long running work for which the progressbar indicates progress done in a separate thread or in the UI thread? If in the UI thread, it would explain why you only see the last one and you would need to do the background work asynchronously and use a dispatcher to update the 'ProgressValue' property

Comment: @user469104: I am already doing in a separate thread. I updated my post. Can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

BradleyDotNET is right.

You've got PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel set to High. That will cause a bunch of information to print regarding the binding.

[MSDN on PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I understand that. Can you let me know if you see any issue with code above. Why doesn't ProgressBar get updated?

Comment: Oh sorry. I misunderstood. What `type` is pMeter?

Comment: Can you print the value of pMeter to the console in your delegate to make sure the action is actually getting called often enough?

Comment: pMeter is of type double. Yes, the delegate is called with several values that range from 0 to 100.

Comment: Have you tried updating `ProgressValue` using a different mechanism? Perhaps comment out how you're currently doing it, and set up a simple `DispatcherTimer` that ticks every second and adds 1.0f to `ProgressValue`. Also, check that `ProgressValue` is set up correctly. Is it a DependencyProperty or a POCO property? If a POCO property, is the PropertyChanged event firing whenever `ProgressValue` gets assigned to?